# Get 1 Month low price of a stock with Google Finance using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-finance

For 1 Month low: I tried this Code in Google Sheet does not working

```
enter code here
```

=MIN(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("NYSE:UBER","price",DATE(MONTH(TODAY()-30,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())), TODAY()),0,2))

Does not returning any value

Comment: Your date element is incorrect, I receive an error message that says "Wrong number of arguments to DATE. Expected 3 arguments, but received 2 arguments."

Comment: @A.Steer Can you tell me what is exactly wrong - =MIN(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("NYSE:UBER","price",DATE(MONTH(TODAY()-30,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())), TODAY()),0,2))

Answer (score 0):

When entered into Google sheets your formula comes up with the following error message:

```
"Wrong number of arguments to DATE. Expected 3 arguments, but received 2 arguments."
```

Looking at the formula there are a number of issues -

The date function is being fed three elements, but they do not make up a correct date. The function is being fed the month value twice instead of a year, month, day value.

So

```
=DATE(MONTH(TODAY()-30,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))
```

should be

```
=DATE(year(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()-30),DAY(TODAY()))
```

In your original formula there is also a ) bracket missing as part of the year element of the date formula, so the formula wasen't returning the right number of elements.

When viewing the [Google Docs editors help file webpage](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en-GB), if your intention is to return the low value of a stock, you are also using the incorrect attribute element to pull this value out. You have used "price" which returns

> ‘price’ – Real-time price quote, delayed by up to 20 minutes.

but should be using

> 'low' – The current day's low price.

Again referancing the [Google Docs editors help file webpage](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en-GB) you can also shorten your date element to only use the TODAY()-30 element instead of entering the a full date string.

As such your origional formula can be changed from:

```
=MIN(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("NYSE:UBER","price",DATE(MONTH(TODAY()-30,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())), TODAY()),0,2))
```

to

```
=MIN(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("NYSE:UBER","price",MONTH(TODAY()-30), TODAY()),0,2))
```